# Shell script to copy a file to a location displayed on the terminal after the build

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, terminal

I have written a shell script for automation. I want to know how to get the location displayed on the terminal into a variable and use that variable that contains the location to copy that particular file in that location to another location.

To be more specific:
I have run a command say "build" file name.
After the file is successfully compiled it displays the location in which the file is stored on the terminal.
I want to copy files from that location displayed on the screen to another location.

Thanks in advance !:)

Comment: Are you using a make file to compile? Then you just add the copy command after the compilation. Or you may can use "pwd" to get the actual path.

Comment: Could you share your thoughts on how you'd attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: So, when you type 'build somefile', it creates somefile _somewhere_? Looks strange, please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your build command only outputs the resulting output file, you can feed it to 
`xargs` and `cp`, for example like this:

```
$ ./build.sh | xargs -I % cp % target_folder
```

This will feed the output of `build.sh` to `xargs`, which will take the output and feed it to `cp`. If you have some other messages as well, then you will have to do some line processing.
For example let's say you have some build messages there as well etc.

```
$ ./build.sh
"Building ver 23"
"bla bla"
"Build complete:"
"/path/to/build/dir/output1"
"/path/to/build/dir/output2"
```

We can `grep` for example the current path (command `pwd`) or the target build path (or something else you know, for example is there a fixed binary name that is not in the log messages )?:

```
$ ./build.sh | grep `pwd` | xargs -I % cp % target_folder
```

Edit: whoops a typo, `-I` of course for the input parameter, not +I